# how create static class with function after function call same as eloquent or may jquery

Tags: php, function, oop, eloquent

I don't know what is this call system.

For example:

```
$a = SameClass::fnc1()->fnc2('input')->fnc2();
```

and we can see this method in jQuery:

```
$("#selector").parent().css('left',5).fadeOut(1500);
```

I don't have any idea to write this codes structure in PHP.

Comment: use  `return $this;`. its called Chaining  Call

Comment: @splash58 can you explain more bro?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return object from a function

For example

```
class First
{
    public function funcFirst()
    {
        $obj = new Second;
        return $obj;
    }
}

class Second
{
    public function funcSecond($message)
    {
        return $message;
    }
}

$first = new First;
$message = "Hello";
$result = $first->funcFirst()->funcSecond($message); // 'Hello'
```

Comment: The first function is unknown we can't use this.

Comment: @jozvo What do you mean?

Comment: I need one class and i don't know what is the first function call some times `fnc1` sometimes `fnc2` call first.

Comment: @jozvo To my knowledge you can't do this with static methods

Comment: In Laravel models: `User::where()->get()` or `User::all()` the first methods is not same.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think that it uses one class

Comment: It's help me but not my answer +1